# unsupported opperand type error. i am using python version 3

Tags: python-3.x

I AM USING PYTHON VERSION 3.5 AND TYPING THIS CODE FOR PRIME NUMBER :::

```
         num=input("enter number to be checked :    ")
         ctr=0
         i=1
         for i in range(1,(num/2)+1):
                 if(num%i==0):
                 ctr+=1

         if(ctr==0):
                 print(num,"    is prime")
         else:
                 print(num,"    is not prime")
```

AND GETTING THIS ERROR::::

```
         enter number to be checked :   5
         Traceback (most recent call last)
           file "prime.py", line 4 in (module)
                 for i in range(1,(num/2)+1):
         type error: unsupported opperand type(s) for/:str and int
```

Comment: read your input as `int` like `num=int(input("enter number to be checked :    "))`.

Answer (score 0):

when using `input()` it is a string value, not an `int`

change to

```
num=int(input("enter number to be checked :    "))
```

This however will produce a `ValueError` when a non-numeric value is entered, you might want to build in a check.